How to manage CSS flexbox element size
I have a horizontal line element connected to a nav menu inside of a flexbox container which in turn is inside of a flexbox container as well:

When I resize the window the menu stacks instead of the horizontal line getting shorter. How can I fix it? ( I want menu to stay intact and the line to be the one shrinking)



#menu_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

#menu_align {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 50%;
}

#line_horizontal {
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}

#nav {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000;
  width: 590px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin-right: 9em;
  margin-left: 0em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-left: solid 1px #000;
  border-right: solid 1px #000;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0em;
}

#nav ul li {
  float: right;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="menu_container">
      <!--(flex container)100% of horizontal space across the screen-->
      <div id="menu_align">
        <!--(flex container)50% of horizontal space.Right half of the screen-->
        <div id="line_horizontal"></div>
        <nav id="nav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="logo"> </div>
  </div>
</div>




Please edit your post to include a minimal reproducible example, preferably as a stack snippet.

You should really rather use flexbox all the way - instead of mixing in float.

fixed it by using display:flex in nav ul

your Structure:

In Flex, the performance works like this:
When you give an element display: flex.
This affects the children of that element.
So it wasn't necessary for all elements to have display: flex.
So I just adjusted the sizes and set them with percentages(%) to make it responsive.
Flex has a feature called flex-wrapper.
which can take two values:

no wrap
wrap

The first amount says that in case of a lack of space, I will move the elements to the next line.
The second option says that if there is not enough space, make the elements smaller but keep them in their place.
The issue was resolved by adjusting the width of the nav, and they no longer overflow the box.


body {
  margin: 1%;  /* For a suitable distance from all four sides. */
}

#header,
#wrapper,
#menu_container
 {
  width: 100%;
}
/* parent for nav */
#menu_align {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;  
}

#line_horizontal {
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}

#nav {
  width:max-content;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

#nav>ul {
  border: 1px solid black;     /* I gave this to the border so it can better cover the links. */
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

#nav>ul>li {
  float: right;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>flex-box</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="menu_container"> <!--(flex container)100% of horizontal space across the screen-->
           <div id="menu_align"> <!--(flex container)50% of horizontal space.Right half of the screen-->
                <div id="line_horizontal"></div>
                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul> <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Contact</a</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="logo"> </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>



Good luck!
